# Regarding PHP Pages & Variables

Tags: php

### What I'm Doing & My Problem

I currently have four pages working together:

- `index.php`

  - `dbconfig.php`
  - `databass.class.php`

    - `View_Item.php`

Within `databass.class.php` I have `$API_Key = XXXXXXX;` at the top and further down the page I do an `include` to `View_Item.php`.

Viewing `index.php`, the echoed HTML content displays however the additional content is not being fetched so I added a test to that page:

```
echo "<h1>\$APK_Key =".$API_Key."</h1>";
```

This is returning nothing, just shows "$APK_Key ="

---

### Questions:

If another PHP page is being included, why is the `$APK_Key` variable not working within the fetched content?

**PLEASE NOTE:** This is not a questions seeking debugging help - I am somewhat new to programming in PHP and would like to know HOW to, not WHY my version is not working.I make this point seeing that a user has voted to close my question under this point.

**Update:**

- `index.php`

  - Calls for `databass.class.php` on line 11 (after HTML doc tags
- `databass.class.php`

  - Calls for `dbconfig.php` on line 1
  - **THEN** my `$API_Key` on line 2
  - `View_Item.php` on line 48

**UPDATE 2:

`databass.class.php` reads:

```
<?php
require("dbconfig.php");
$API_Key = XXXXXXXX;
class MYCLASS { 
    private $conn;
    public function __construct() {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
    public function runQuery($sql) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
    public function prepare($sqls) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqls);
        return $stmt;
    }
    public function itemTypes($type) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT type FROM items WHERE type=:type");
            $stmt->execute(array(':type'=>$type));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                return $stmt->rowCount();
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }           
    }
    public function listItem($type,$name) {
        if ($name) {
            try {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, buy_Price, sell_Price FROM items WHERE type=:type AND name=:name");
                $stmt->execute(array(':type'=>$type, ':name'=>$name));
                $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                echo "<p>
                        <span><div class=\"items\"><div class=\"items-lg items-lg-".$userRow['id']."\"></div></div></span><br>
                        <span>".$userRow['name']."</span><br>
                        <span>".$userRow['buy_Price']."</span><br>
                        <span>".$userRow['sell_Price']."</span>
                    </p><br><br><br><br>";
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            include "../Assets/PHP/Pages/Items/View_Item.php";
        } else {
            try {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, buy_Price, sell_Price FROM items WHERE type=:type");
                $stmt->execute(array(':type'=>$type));
                $userRow=$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                echo "<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IMG</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Buy Price</th>
            <th>Sell Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
                foreach($userRow as $result => $value){
                    echo "\n        <tr>
            <td><div class=\"items\"><div class=\"items-lg items-lg-".$value['id']."\"></div></div></td>
            <td>".$value['name']."</td>
            <td>".$value['buy_Price']."</td>
            <td>".$value['sell_Price']."</td>
        </tr>";
                }
                echo "\n    </tbody>\n</table>";
            }

            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
error_reporting(-1); // reports all errors 
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); // shows all errors 
ini_set("log_errors", 1); 
?>
```

Comment: It has been voted to close as the way you describe your issue, actually **does** work. However, I'd find this a bad practice to do so and this opens the issue of `primarily opinion-based` because while I would not want this to work someone else might.

Comment: Check that $API_Key = XXXXXXX; is not inside some class (i.e. class Database { ... $API_Key = XXXXXXX; ... }), and make sure that files don’t contain namespace definition in the top.

Comment: Can you provide the content of `database.class.php`? I want to make sure that `$API_Key` is not in fact a property of your `Database` class.

Comment: @Spholt I've just edited showing my `database.class.php` script

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables before using them.  If index.php looks like this:

```
echo "<h1>\$API_Key =".$API_Key."</h1>";
include 'databass.class.php';   //where $API_Key is defined
```

You are trying to use `$API_Key` (on line one) before it is defined (in the file on line two).

Put the `include` line first.

Comment: Everything appears to be in the correct order. I have my `$API_Key` then within a class I call for the file which should read the API key further down the page. I'm guessing it is because I include within a class?

Comment: In `index.php` on what line do you output $API_Key?  And on what line do you include `databass.class.php`?

Comment: Oh I thought `index.php` was trying to echo `$API_Key`, but it is actually being output in `View_Item.php` is that correct?

Comment: The code you've pasted here sometimes refers to `$APK_Key` and other times `$API_Key`.  Make sure you are using the right variable name.  Also check the PHP error logs.